# string manipulation : str ing = aaabbcccaa to a3b2c3a2 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone help me in writing code in python  for string manipulation 
string is

```
string = aaabbcccaa
```

output will be

> a3b2c3a2

Comment: we are not here to do your homework. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Edit your question and post the relevant code parts.

Comment: Is there any kind of rule behind this manipulation? Otherwise, try a simple string replacement: if input = "aaabbcccaa", return "a3b2c3a2"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tip to get you started:

1) Find the length of the string

2) Iterate over the string

3) Use a dictionary to record the count of the letters

4) Iterate over the dictionary to print the result

Hope that helps :)